# Google oAuth 2.0 API Authentication Error: Error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I've seen a bunch of posts talking about this error, and I've tried all the fixes, but nothing seems to work. The main fix they say to do is to put the url that is shown in the error into the list of Authorized redirect URIs. But the issue is that the generated url is different every time. http://localhost:50509 one time, then http://localhost:50624 the next, then http://localhost:50633. I've included all these URIs but it doesn't fix anything.

**Specifics**:

- I am trying to connect to gmail through Visual Studio Code with python. I'm running gmail's official quickstart.py code/program.  The error gets thrown when I run it and it opens gmail.
- I have http://localhost:5000, http://localhost:8080, and many of the other urls I discussed above in the Authorized redirect URIs section.
- I have filled out the OAuth 2.0 consent form
- I have created an API key
- I have enabled the gmail API
- I have downloaded the OAuth client JSON file, named it "credentials", and put it in my working directory.

What else can I do??????? Nothing is working.

Comment: You need to fix your allocation so it runs from a static port and doesn't give you a different port everytime you run it